# Electrons crossection distribution inside a direct current wire

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, electric-current

If electrons of a DC flow feel mutual magnetic field that should move them towards the center of the wire and in that case their accumulation in the center cause electric repulsion should there be a complicated crossection area distribution of electrons inside the wire. (Also when electrons accumulate in the center the Newton field law sugests that the positive exterior of the wire should not attract these electrons.)

Comment: This appears to be discussed in Matzek & Russell, Am. J. Phys. **36**, 905 (1968).  However, I don't have institutional access beyond the first page, otherwise I would write up a summary as an answer.